# Dalvik application(apk) loader

Tags: android, dalvik

I want to know where is the application loader in Dalvik source code. 
    In fact,I prepare to modify the Byte-code verification process of Dalvik Machine, but I'd like that my modification make change only for application(apk) load process.So I need to know the entry of application loader in order to add my modification.

Comment: I think that's the zygote part: http://coltf.blogspot.de/p/android-os-processes-and-zygote.html

Comment: Please provide more specific details about the problem like what you have tried and where you are facing problems, so that we can help you in a better way.